# KnockoutJS animated transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Can anyone explain why the animated transition example in the knockoutjs website [here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html) uses the template binding? The example uses this:

```
 <div data-bind='template: { foreach: planetsToShow,
                            beforeRemove: hidePlanetElement,
                            afterAdd: showPlanetElement }'>
    <div data-bind='attr: { "class": "planet " + type }, text: name'> </div>
</div>
```

But the following works just as well:

```
 <div data-bind='foreach: {data: planetsToShow,
                            beforeRemove: hidePlanetElement,
                            afterAdd: showPlanetElement}'>
    <div data-bind='attr: { "class": "planet " + type }, text: name'> </div>
</div>
```

Here is their original [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/8k8V5/). Here is my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8k8V5/2191/). The use of the template binding seems extraneous. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There is no special reason why the sample uses the `template` binding.

On the [top of the page](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html) it is even mentioned:

> **When using the template/foreach binding**, you can provide afterAdd and beforeRemove callbacks.

So it does not matter whether you use the `foreach` binding or the `template` binding in "foreach mode", because [internally](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/foreach.js) the  `foreach` binding just delegates back to the `template` binding.

So they are essentially doing the same thing only with different syntax, however you have more options if you are directly using the `template` binding:

The main difference is that when using the `foreach` binding you cannot use named templates you have to use the inline template, but the in `template` binding you can specify any template even change it dynamically.

Comment: I do not believe that that statement means template *or* foreach. I believe they are saying "Using the combination of the template and foreach binding, you can...". Further, the example on the page has no need of the template, so it should either be changed to need a template or changed as I have done in the fiddle. If your interpretation is correct, then that really should be reworded to make it more clear.

Comment: No, the "template/foreach" really means template OR foreach because as I said (and you can also check in the code) that the `foreach` is essentially the simplified case of the `template` binding (so anything what you can do with the `foreach` can be done also the template binding but you there are some feature of the `template` binding like the named tempaltes what you cannot achieve the `foreach`). So you can use either one to achieve the same effect. But for this sample probably the `template` was not best choice for the demonstration.

Comment: Our interpretation of that sentence is really beside the point of my original question :-). Let me restate: 

Would someone ever wrap your foreach with a template binding, as they did in the example, when you are not using a named template in the first place? 

The example is not using a named template. So my question was why did they do that if they aren't using a named template? Was there some reason or was it just a mistake? It sounds like from your last statement that you feel it was not the best example either.

Comment: I personally only use the template binding with named templates. So I would never use the template binding in a foreach mode with an inline template. So yes the example is too artifical but it is still an example to demonstrate the event handler. And maybe the API was not always like this so it can be the example remained from an old version when the foreach binding does not had the `afterAdd` and `beforeRemove` events and they had to use the template bindings for this but this is just some speculation.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing...that it was a leftover from a previous version. I forgot to thank you for taking the time to respond..so thank you. :-)